# Tuner with only numbers

Tags: guitar, classical-guitar, tuner

I havea clip-on tuner for my Classical Guitar that only shows numbers from 2 to 6 How do I tune my Guitar with that tuner?

Comment: Do you have a model number? There might be a manual on the internet somewhere.

Comment: Tell us the make and model of the tuner please?

Comment: Or a picture of the tuner. Or of some tuna.

Comment: It's called Sheffield ET-06G Cliptuner, It came along with the Guitar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a *1* as well on your tuner. I also have such a tuner made by Sanchez. The numbers represent the strings, *1* being the high E string and *6* the low E string.

These tuners' displays sometimes change colours according to the pitch of the string, yellow for below tone, green for in tune and red for over tensioned string. The issue is that the range is quite small, from perfect pitch, the tuner only goes to about 1/4 step sharp and 1/4 step flat.

To tune your guitar, you will need to use your ears, this will be difficult when you are a beginner. Start with the low E, and get it as close as possible to tune using your ear. If you are close enough, the tuner will pick it up, and then you can make small adjustments to get it in tune. Once the low E is sorted, use the ancient way of tuning, ie, using the 5th fret on the low E to tune the A string, etc. This should get your guitar close to perfect tuning. Your tuner should now pick up each string, so you will be able to use your tuner to fine tune each string

This is how I atleat do it with my tuner, and it works perfectly for me. The only issue with these type of tuners is that you can only tune a guitar to standard, so you might be at a loss for alternative tunings. On fixed bridge guitars, alternative tuning is not that hard, the real issue is with floating bridges as tuning one string will affect the pitch of another, but again, the net has a lot of info on this which you can research if you ever need an alternatuve tuning

Answer (score 0):

These tuners are very limited. The numbers refer to the number of the string. Normally, 6 referees to the lowest tuned string, 1 the highest. If your guitar is at least close to the proper tuning, it will show you how to get fully in tune. And if you are very far out of tune, it will be difficult to tune properly. Also, you will not be able to do any sort of alternate tuning, or tune any other instruments.